# Error with toolbox loading in scilab

Tags: opencv, scilab

I am trying to link a cpp file with Scilab 5.5.2, using  the following code

```
// This file is released under the 3-clause BSD license. See COPYING-BSD.
function builder_gw_cpp()   
    WITHOUT_AUTO_PUTLHSVAR = %t; 
    tbx_build_gateway("skeleton_cpp9990", ..    
    ["imread","opencv_imread"], ..
    ["opencv_imread.cpp"], .. 
    get_absolute_file_path("builder_gateway_cpp.sce"),[],"g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename opencv_imread.cpp .cpp` opencv_imread.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`");
endfunction

builder_gw_cpp(); 
clear    builder_gw_cpp;    // remove builder_gw_cpp on stack
```

When I execute these commands:

```
 1)exec builder_gateway_cpp.sce
 2)exec loader.sce.
```

I get an error like this:

```
addinter(libskeleton_cpp6969_path + filesep() + 'libskeleton_cpp69690' + getdynlibext(), 'libskeleton_cpp69690', list_functions);
Link failed for dynamic library '/home/tess/work/functions/imcrop//libskeleton_cpp69690.so'.
An error occurred: /home/tess/work/functions/imcrop//libskeleton_cpp69690.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3Mat10deallocateEv
Link failed for dynamic library '/home/tess/work/functions/imcrop//libskeleton_cpp69690.so'.
An error occurred: /home/tess/work/functions/imcrop//libskeleton_cpp69690.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3Mat10deallocateEv
dynlibext(), 'libskeleton_cpp69690', list_functions)
                                                     !--error 236 
addinter: The shared archive was not loaded: (null)
at line      15 of exec file called by :    
exec loader.sce
```

The symbols are found in libopencv_imgproc.

- How do I ensure the code finds the required libraries?

Comment: What is the output of `ldd /home/tess/work/functions/imcrop//libskeleton_cpp69690.so`?

Comment: linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff31dfc000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f15df9d9000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f15df614000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f15df3fd000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f15df0f7000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f15dfeff000)

Comment: There are no opencv libs linked, see my answer below for the probable cause.

Answer (score 0):

According to [tbx_build_gateway docs](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/tbx_build_gateway.html) you are providing:

```
tbx_build_gateway(libname, names, files, [gateway_path [, libs [, ldflags [, cflags [, fflags [, cc [, makename [, ismex]]]]]]]])

libname = "skeleton_cpp9990"
names = "imread", "opencv_imread"
files = opencv_imread.cpp
gateway_path = get_absolute_file_path("builder_gateway_cpp.sce")
libs = []
ldflags= "g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename opencv_imread.cpp .cpp` opencv_imread.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`"
cflags = 
fflags = 
cc = 
makename = 
ismex =
```

I'm not an expert in `tbx_build_gateway` but I could imagine that ldflags is not the appropriate field to provide your build command, I would expect something more like the following:

```
libname = "skeleton_cpp9990"
names = "imread", "opencv_imread"
files = opencv_imread.cpp
gateway_path = get_absolute_file_path("builder_gateway_cpp.sce")
libs = ["opencv","opencv_imgproc"]
ldflags= 
cflags = "-ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename opencv_imread.cpp .cpp` opencv_imread.cpp `pkg-config`"
fflags = 
cc = "g++"
makename = 
ismex =
```

Comment: Now my tbx_build-gateway()  like this  :-tbx_build_gateway("skeleton_cpp9990",..
["imread","opencv_imread"],..
["opencv_imread.cpp"],.. 
get_absolute_file_path("builder_gateway_cpp.sce"),["opencv","opencv_imgproc"],[], "-ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o `basename opencv_imread.cpp .cpp` opencv_imread.cpp `pkg-config`",[],"g++");

Comment: I got error like this :-Detection of C/C++/Fortran Compilers 
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c 
checking whether build environment is sane... yes 
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p 
checking for gawk... no 
checking for mawk... mawk 
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes 
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes 
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no 
checking for gcc... g++ 
checking whether the C compiler works... no 
 !--error 10000

Comment: When looking at the builder_gateway_cpp.sce file in the [toolbox skeleton](http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/toolbox_skeleton) I see they don't specify the compiler explicitly. You could try without it.